# Python/Django: Are there any decorators to tell that input is not none?

Tags: python, django

- I am new to Django and come from Java/Spring background.
- I am wondering if there are decorators something like following that can be done in Django or Python?

**Want**

```
def addToList(@not_none a, @not_none b):
    # so that I do not check for nullity explicitly  
    do_things_with_a(a)
    do_things_with_b(b)
```

- Since this is something which is pretty easy to get in Java, just looking if Python/Django has it

Comment: What does it mean for an input to be "null"?

Comment: That ain't decorator syntax. Decorators are at the function or class level, not the argument level. Anyway, this isn't the way things tend to be done in Python.

Comment: It will *never* be `None` unless you explicitly cause or allow it to be.

Comment: I should say that my answer below is for rejecting None arguments in a function. It won't automatically create a Djang error page or stop processing the request / form. If you want form input to be validated you need to read more about form validation in the Django documentation (in particular the `clean()` method of a form).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One doesn't typically constraint data-types in Python. Also, decorators can only be applied to classes and to methods/functions.

Although, you shouldn't really be doing this, this is how you would.

(You could amend this to accept argument names to enforce constraints on with a little work).

```
def not_none(f):
    def func(*args, **kwargs):
        if any(arg is None for arg in args):
            raise ValueError('function {}: does not take arguments of None'.format(f.__name__))
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return func

@not_none
def test(a, b):
    print a, b
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write a decorator `rejectNone` as follows:

```
def rejectNone(f):
    def myF(*args, **kwargs):
        if None in args or None in kwargs.values():
            raise Exception('One of the arguments passed to {0} is None.'.format(f.__name__)
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return myF

@rejectNone
def f(a, b, k=3):
   print a * b
```

You will now get an `Exception` if you try to call `f` with a `None` argument. Note that decorators can be applied to functions or class methods but you can't put them in front of function parameters.

Comment: You're not returning `f(*args, **kwargs)` from `myF`

Answer (score 1):

I know this is late, but to those who it may be helpful.

I have a simple repo based off of Jon's answer that accepts arguments for nullable fields [here](https://github.com/bigbob556677/python-not-none).

---

```
def not_none(nullable_parameters=None):

    def the_actual_test(f, args, filter_array):
        has_none = False
        bad_parameters = []

        if type(filter_array) is str:

            filter_array = [filter_array]

        if not filter_array:

            if any(arg[1] is None for arg in args):
                raise ValueError('function {}: Parameters cannot be None. '.format(f.__name__))

        elif type(filter_array) is list:
            for a in args:
                for ff in filter_array:
                    if a[0] != ff:
                        if a[1] is None:
                            has_none = True
                            bad_parameters.append(a[0])
                            break

        if has_none:
            raise ValueError('function {}: Parameters {} cannot be None. '.format(f.__name__, bad_parameters))

    def real_decorator(f):


        v_names = f.__code__.co_varnames

        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            n_args = []

            for a in range(0, len(args)):
                n_args.append((v_names[a], args[a]))

            the_actual_test(f, n_args, nullable_parameters)
            result = f(*args, **kwargs)

            return result
        return wrapper

    return real_decorator
```

**Usage**

```
from not_none import not_none

@not_none()
def no_none(a,b):
    return (a,b)

@not_none(nullable_parameters=["b"])
def allow_b_as_none(a,b):
    return (a,b)

#passes
no_none(1,1)

#fails
no_none(None,1)

#passes
allow_b_as_none(1,None)

#fails
allow_b_as_none(None,1)
```

Answer (score 1):

After my first answer got deleted. Here is an updated version:

I tried to use the very nice answer from [Bigbob556677](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8521346/bigbob556677), but for me it didn't work with `**kwargs`, so I edited it and put it in a Gist, here: https://gist.github.com/devTechi/6e633ded72cc83637f34b1a3f4a96984 (code also below)

I didn't test it with just `*args`, but with (I posted more or less just the gist-link) `**kwargs` it works nicely.

```
def not_none(nullable_parameters=None):
  # values given by real_decorator (see below)
  def the_actual_test(f, expected_args_with_given, allowed_nullable_args):
    has_none = False
    bad_parameters = []

    for key, value in expected_args_with_given.items():
      if (value is None and nullable_parameters is None) or \
              (value is None and key not in nullable_parameters):
        bad_parameters.append(key)
        has_none = True

    if has_none:
      raise ValueError("[Function '{}' of '{}'] - IMPORTANT: Parameters '{}' cannot be None. ".format(f.__name__, f.__module__, bad_parameters))

  # here the code REALLY begins
  def not_null_decorator(original_func):
    import inspect
    has_self = False
    # f.__code__.co_varnames --> local variables (not only parameters), see: https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/code/varnames.html
    # get declared arguments from ogirinal function
    argspec = inspect.getargspec(original_func)
    if 'self' in argspec.args:
      argnames = argspec.args[1:]  # no self
      has_self = True
    else:
      argnames = argspec.args
    args_dict = dict.fromkeys(argnames)

    def get_args(*args, **kwargs):
      for arg in args:
        if arg in args_dict.keys():
          args_dict[arg] = arg
      for key, value in kwargs.items():
        if key in args_dict.keys():
          args_dict[key] = value

      return args_dict

    def wrapper_with_self(self, *args, **kwargs):
      the_actual_test(original_func, get_args(*args, **kwargs), nullable_parameters)
      return original_func(self, *args, **kwargs)

    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
      the_actual_test(original_func, get_args(*args, **kwargs), nullable_parameters)
      return original_func(*args, **kwargs)

    if has_self:
      return wrapper_with_self
    else:
      return wrapper

  return not_null_decorator
```

Usage:

```
from .nullable_decorator import not_none

@not_none(nullable_parameters=["nullable_arg1", "nullable_arg2"])
def some_function(self, nullable_arg1=None, nullable_arg2=None, non_nullable_arg1=None):
   pass

@not_none()
def some_other_function(self, non_nullable_arg1=None, non_nullable_arg2=None):
   pass
```